# I want to use a modal form on multiple places in my website by adding the code once

Tags: javascript, html, forms

PS - I am a non tech person working on a website for a personal project.

I have been able to create a modal form on my website triggered by the onclick function but right now I am adding the complete form code at every place in the code where I am adding the form. I want to -

1. Add the form html at one place so that I can call it multiple times. JS is already added once but cant find how to call html from one place
2. Hide the form code from view source or basically secure the form by hiding it

```html
<a id="headercta" class="btn" style="color: white;" onclick="myfunc()">Enquire Now</a>
<div id="myModal" class="leadpopup">
   <div class="leadpopup-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h5>Tell us about your trip</h5>
      <hr>
      <div class="mt-4">
         <form action= 
         <!-- ....my html form code......>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

creating a modal is relatively simple with Javascript. Basically, you are changing the CSS property `display` to `none`, when you want to hide the element, or something else, when you want it to be visible. Here is a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Modal example</title>
    <style>
      /* You probably will move the styling into a separate file */
      #headercta {
        color: white;
      } 

      #myModal {
        display: none; /* we start with hidden modal */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        animation: 0.6s; 
      }

      .leadpopup-content {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */

      }

       .close {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        border: none;
        float: right;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="headercta" class="btn" onclick="toggleModal()">Enquire Now</button>
    <div id="myModal" class="leadpopup">
       <div class="leadpopup-content">
          <button class="close" onclick="toggleModal()">&times;</button>
          <h5>Tell us about your trip</h5>
          <hr>
          <div class="mt-4">
           Form goes here... Change as needed.
           <br>
           <br>
           <form action="/action">
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Personalia:</legend>
              <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
              <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
              <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
              <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
              <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
              <textarea id="message" name="message" style="width: 95%;">
                The trip was amzingly awesome, because...
              </textarea> 
              <br>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </fieldset>
          </form> 
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      /* You probably will move Javascript into a separate file */
      let toggled = false
      const toggleModal = () => {
        const modal = document.getElementById("myModal")
        toggled = !toggled
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Modal example</title>
    <style>
      /* You probably will move the styling into a separate file */
      #headercta {
        color: white;
      } 

      #myModal {
        display: none; /* we start with hidden modal */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        animation: 0.6s; 
      }

      .leadpopup-content {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */

      }


       .close {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        border: none;
        float: right;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="headercta" class="btn" onclick="toggleModal()">Enquire Now</button>
    <div id="myModal" class="leadpopup">
       <div class="leadpopup-content">
          <button class="close" onclick="toggleModal()">&times;</button>
          <h5>Tell us about your trip</h5>
          <hr>
          <div class="mt-4">
           Form goes here...
           <br>
           <br>
           <form action="/action">
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Personalia:</legend>
              <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
              <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
              <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
              <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
              <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
              <textarea id="message" name="message" style="width: 95%;">
                The trip was amzingly awesome, because...
              </textarea> 
              <br>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </fieldset>
          </form> 
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      /* You probably will move Javascript into a separate file */
      let toggled = false
      const toggleModal = () => {
        const modal = document.getElementById("myModal")
        toggled = !toggled

        if(toggled) {
          modal.style.display = "inline" // this can be changed to block, or inline-block
        } else {
          modal.style.display = "none" // this hides the modal, when the button is pressed even number of times
        }
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>

      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can add the button wherever you want/need to, allowing the user to open the modal in different ways. Calling the `toggleModal` function will always toggle the state of this specific modal, so if you have other modals, you may need to create another function, or generalize the existing one. It would probably be possible to create a closure function that remembers the CSS selector and the `toggle` state. Something along lines:

```
function getToggleFunction(cssSelector) {
  let toggled = false
  const selector = cssSelector
  const modal = document.getElementById(selector)

  return () => {
        if(toggled) {
          modal.style.display = "inline"
        } else {
          modal.style.display = "none" 
        }
     }
   }
}

const toggleModal = getToggleFunction("myModal")
const toggleSomethingElse = getToggleFunction("somethingElse")
```

Then you can use them in events as `onclick:"toggleModal()"` and `onclick:"toggleSomethingElse()"`, respectively. Of course, you need to add the `display: hide;` into the style sheet for each modal.

I hope this will be helpful.